# SQL Group By: Get values of 'max' record

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a `scores` table:

```
id
user
score
date
```

Now, I can easily select a top 10 highscore with

```
SELECT user, score, date FROM scores ORDER BY score DESC
```

However, I'd like to include only one score per user, namely his highest. I would begin with something like

```
SELECT user, MAX(score) AS score FROM scores GROUP BY user ORDER BY score DESC
```

However, now I've lost the `date` that highest score was recorded. How do I get it?

Answer (score 1):

You can `JOIN` on the table again:

```
SELECT s1.user, max(s1.dt), s2.mxscore as score
FROM scores s1
inner join 
(
    select user, max(score) mxscore
    from scores
    GROUP BY user 
) s2
    on s1.user = s2.user
    and s1.score = s2.mxscore
GROUP BY s1.username, s2.mxscore
ORDER BY score DESC
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/967d8/6)

Comment: What happens if there's more than one date with the same score?

Comment: It's unlikely that the `id` field is the user ID, but rather an auto-incremented field which acts as a primary key for each scoring instance.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, you don't need a `GROUP BY` at all.

Here's the query:

```
SELECT scores.id, scores.user, scores.score, scores.date
FROM scores
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * 
  FROM scores AS _scores
  WHERE _scores.user = scores.user
  AND (
    _scores.score > scores.score
    OR
    _scores.score = scores.score AND _scores.id < scores.id) 
)
```

and [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ac9a/1) to see it working.

Note that this query properly handles the case when a user had his max score several times (it returns the record for the first max score).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to relate your result with your original table:

```
select a.user, a.maxScore, b.maxDate
from (
    select user, max(score) as maxScore 
    from scores group by user ) as a
inner join (
    select user, score, max(date) as maxDate 
    from scores group by user, score) as b on a.user = b.user and a.maxScore=b.score
order by
    a.maxScore desc
```

This query will return the maximum score for each user, and the last date when this maximum score was scored (redundant, but true)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT   a.*
FROM     scores a
JOIN     (
         SELECT   MAX(a.id) AS id
         FROM     scores a
         JOIN     (
                  SELECT   user, MAX(score) AS score
                  FROM     scores
                  GROUP BY user
                  ) b ON a.user  = b.user
                     AND a.score = b.score
         GROUP BY a.user, 
                  a.score
         ) b ON a.id = b.id
ORDER BY a.score DESC
```

This will account for cases where you have more than one of the same highest score per user. In that case, it will just take the maximum `id`.